# SAPUI5: Reset ComboBox based on another ComboBox's Change/selectionChange

Tags: combobox, sapui5, reset, sap-fiori

I have 4 ComboBoxes: A, B, C, D.

If I change/selectionChange A, then B, C, D's value  are reset.
If I change/selectionChange B, then C, D's value  are reset.
If I change/selectionChange C, then D's value  is reset.

What's the simplest way I can code this? I assume each ComboBox will need a unique id?

Comment: It's possible to do this only with your (json) model. You can attach a change handler to the different bindings of "selectedKey". But if you want a quick solution then yes, give each combobox a unique ID and implement an event handler for the comboboxes change event.